# Trying to add bootstrap into my VUE CLI and it's not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, eslint, vue-cli, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to add bootstrap into my Vue CLI project and I don't know if it works. I am following the get started link by Bootstrap https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs and I always get stuck..

First I run the: "yarn add vue bootstrap bootstrap-vue" command in the directory where my project is stored. This part works fine, but next it's asking me to import these files into the main.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'

// Import Bootstrap and BootstrapVue CSS files (order is important)
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

// Make BootstrapVue available throughout your project
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
// Optionally install the BootstrapVue icon components plugin
Vue.use(IconsPlugin)
```

---

So this is what I have now in the main.js file:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Vue from 'vue'
import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'

// Import Bootstrap and BootstrapVue CSS files (order is important)
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

// Make BootstrapVue available throughout your project
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
// Optionally install the BootstrapVue icon components plugin
Vue.use(IconsPlugin)

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

And this is the error/warning I receive when running the app:

```
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of /Users/rubencapota/project-vue/node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/icons/icons.js as it exceeds the m

 WARNING  Compiled with 2 warnings                                      18:52:41

 warning  in ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/vue.js

export 'default' (reexported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue' (possible exports: BaseTransition, Comment, EffectScope, Fragment, KeepAlive, ReactiveEffect, Static, Suspense, Teleport, Text, Transition, TransitionGroup, VueElement, callWithAsyncErrorHandling, callWithErrorHandling, camelize, capitalize, cloneVNode, compatUtils, compile, computed, createApp, createBlock, createCommentVNode, createElementBlock, createElementVNode, createHydrationRenderer, createPropsRestProxy, createRenderer, createSSRApp, createSlots, createStaticVNode, createTextVNode, createVNode, customRef, defineAsyncComponent, defineComponent, defineCustomElement, defineEmits, defineExpose, defineProps, defineSSRCustomElement, devtools, effect, effectScope, getCurrentInstance, getCurrentScope, getTransitionRawChildren, guardReactiveProps, h, handleError, hydrate, initCustomFormatter, initDirectivesForSSR, inject, isMemoSame, isProxy, isReactive, isReadonly, isRef, isRuntimeOnly, isShallow, isVNode, markRaw, mergeDefaults, mergeProps, nextTick, normalizeClass, normalizeProps, normalizeStyle, onActivated, onBeforeMount, onBeforeUnmount, onBeforeUpdate, onDeactivated, onErrorCaptured, onMounted, onRenderTracked, onRenderTriggered, onScopeDispose, onServerPrefetch, onUnmounted, onUpdated, openBlock, popScopeId, provide, proxyRefs, pushScopeId, queuePostFlushCb, reactive, readonly, ref, registerRuntimeCompiler, render, renderList, renderSlot, resolveComponent, resolveDirective, resolveDynamicComponent, resolveFilter, resolveTransitionHooks, setBlockTracking, setDevtoolsHook, setTransitionHooks, shallowReactive, shallowReadonly, shallowRef, ssrContextKey, ssrUtils, stop, toDisplayString, toHandlerKey, toHandlers, toRaw, toRef, toRefs, transformVNodeArgs, triggerRef, unref, useAttrs, useCssModule, useCssVars, useSSRContext, useSlots, useTransitionState, vModelCheckbox, vModelDynamic, vModelRadio, vModelSelect, vModelText, vShow, version, warn, watch, watchEffect, watchPostEffect, watchSyncEffect, withAsyncContext, withCtx, withDefaults, withDirectives, withKeys, withMemo, withModifiers, withScopeId)

 warning  in ./src/main.js

export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue' (possible exports: BaseTransition, Comment, EffectScope, Fragment, KeepAlive, ReactiveEffect, Static, Suspense, Teleport, Text, Transition, TransitionGroup, VueElement, callWithAsyncErrorHandling, callWithErrorHandling, camelize, capitalize, cloneVNode, compatUtils, compile, computed, createApp, createBlock, createCommentVNode, createElementBlock, createElementVNode, createHydrationRenderer, createPropsRestProxy, createRenderer, createSSRApp, createSlots, createStaticVNode, createTextVNode, createVNode, customRef, defineAsyncComponent, defineComponent, defineCustomElement, defineEmits, defineExpose, defineProps, defineSSRCustomElement, devtools, effect, effectScope, getCurrentInstance, getCurrentScope, getTransitionRawChildren, guardReactiveProps, h, handleError, hydrate, initCustomFormatter, initDirectivesForSSR, inject, isMemoSame, isProxy, isReactive, isReadonly, isRef, isRuntimeOnly, isShallow, isVNode, markRaw, mergeDefaults, mergeProps, nextTick, normalizeClass, normalizeProps, normalizeStyle, onActivated, onBeforeMount, onBeforeUnmount, onBeforeUpdate, onDeactivated, onErrorCaptured, onMounted, onRenderTracked, onRenderTriggered, onScopeDispose, onServerPrefetch, onUnmounted, onUpdated, openBlock, popScopeId, provide, proxyRefs, pushScopeId, queuePostFlushCb, reactive, readonly, ref, registerRuntimeCompiler, render, renderList, renderSlot, resolveComponent, resolveDirective, resolveDynamicComponent, resolveFilter, resolveTransitionHooks, setBlockTracking, setDevtoolsHook, setTransitionHooks, shallowReactive, shallowReadonly, shallowRef, ssrContextKey, ssrUtils, stop, toDisplayString, toHandlerKey, toHandlers, toRaw, toRef, toRefs, transformVNodeArgs, triggerRef, unref, useAttrs, useCssModule, useCssVars, useSSRContext, useSlots, useTransitionState, vModelCheckbox, vModelDynamic, vModelRadio, vModelSelect, vModelText, vShow, version, warn, watch, watchEffect, watchPostEffect, watchSyncEffect, withAsyncContext, withCtx, withDefaults, withDirectives, withKeys, withMemo, withModifiers, withScopeId)


  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/ 
  - Network: http://192.168.0.209:8080/

[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of /Users/rubencapota/project-vue/node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/icons/icons.js as it exceeds the m

 WARNING  Compiled with 2 warnings                                      18:52:41

 warning  in ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/vue.js

export 'default' (reexported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue' (possible exports: BaseTransition, Comment, EffectScope, Fragment, KeepAlive, ReactiveEffect, Static, Suspense, Teleport, Text, Transition, TransitionGroup, VueElement, callWithAsyncErrorHandling, callWithErrorHandling, camelize, capitalize, cloneVNode, compatUtils, compile, computed, createApp, createBlock, createCommentVNode, createElementBlock, createElementVNode, createHydrationRenderer, createPropsRestProxy, createRenderer, createSSRApp, createSlots, createStaticVNode, createTextVNode, createVNode, customRef, defineAsyncComponent, defineComponent, defineCustomElement, defineEmits, defineExpose, defineProps, defineSSRCustomElement, devtools, effe
```

When I run the application I just see a blank page in the browser and not the one that Vue creates by default.
Sorry for this stupid question and thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You try to use the lib with incompatible Vue version. You need to always check the version a lib is supposed to work with. https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/5196

Comment: You say you are *"following get started link by Bootstrap [https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs)"*, but you skipped the very first bullet point: *"Vue.js v2.6 is required, v2.6.12 is recommended"*.  Change Vue version in `package.json` to `"vue": "@2"` and it will work.

Comment: I did that, also changed the bootstrap version into the required one I still get the same error. this is how my package.json looks like now."dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^4.6.1",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0"
  }